# How do you access a procedure's local variables in a namespace eval {} inside that same procedure?

Tags: tcl

I'm sure I'm just being stupid but would you please tell me how to get access to `$name` inside the namespace in order to set variable `n` to `$name`? I can only find how to do this when the procedure is in the namespace but not the other way 'round. No matter what I try, this errors stating `no such variable name`. Thank you.

```
proc getNS {name} {
  namespace eval ns::$name {
    variable n $name
  }
}
```

This works but isn't really an answer unless the answer is simply that it cannot be done directly. Got it from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560668/importing-proc-variable-into-namespace). Bryan Oakley gave the answer but used `[list set...]` instead of `[list variable...]` and that will fail if there is a global variable of the same name. (It will modify the global rather than creating a new variable in the namespace.) It may have been different, of course, in 2009 when that answer was provided.

```
proc getNS {name} {
  namespace eval ns::$name [list variable n $name]
  namespace eval ns::$name {
    variable a abc
  }
}
set n xyz
getNS WEBS
chan puts stdout "ns n: $ns::WEBS::n; a $ns::WEBS::a, global n: $n"
# => ns n: WEBS; a: abc; global n: xyz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `set` with a fully qualified variable name that uses the desired namespace:

```
proc getNS {name} {
    namespace eval ns::$name {} ;# Create namespace if it doesn't already exist                                                                                                                                                                  
    set ns::${name}::n $name
}

getNS foo
puts $ns::foo::n ;# foo
```

Another way is to use [`uplevel`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/uplevel.html) to refer to the scope of the proc that calls `namespace eval`:

```
proc getNS {name} {
    namespace eval ns::$name {
        set n [uplevel 1 {set name}]
    }
}
```